# Algorithm to count natural numbers

Tags: c

I am creating an algorithm to count natural numbers however the output is a long number:

```
1532752%
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumN(int N){
    int S = 0;
    int I = 1;
    int *p = &I;
    for(int i = *p; i < N; i++){
        S += S + i;
        I += i + 1;

        if( i <= N){
            continue;
        }
    }
    return S;
}

int main(void){
    int N = 15;
    printf("%i", sumN(N));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am new to C and would appreciate feedback because I am likely missing much technical information.

Comment: `S+=S+i` should be `S+=i` but your code is very strangely written.

Comment: What output do you expect?  And what exactly do you mean by "counting" natural numbers?  Because that's not what your program in fact does.

Comment: (a) Do you want to sum natural numbers, not count them? For inputs of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, should the outputs be 1, 3, 6, 10, and 15? If not, show what the outputs should be for those inputs. (b) Why do you use `int *p = &I;`? Were you told you had to use pointers for this assignment? (c) Why do you have `i` and `I` instead of just one of them?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good point, I did not think it out. Yes, I would need to sum the natural numbers. I was actually testing pointers and wanted to see whether it performs exactly like ```int i = 1```, and it does. The formula I was using using `I` but it was not written in C, so I do not need it.

Answer (score 3):

Simple version

```
 int sum =0;
 For (int i =1; i<=N; i++){
     sum += i;
  }
```

This ignores the even simpler n*(n+1)/2 formula

Comment: What is the `n*(n-1)` formula?  The only related formula I know is `sum = n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: @abelenky - my bad , trying to remeber off the top of my head, head tested with 3, which worked :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumN(int N)
{
    return N*(N+1)/2;
}

int sumN2(int N)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i=1; i<=N; sum+=i++);
    return sum;
}

int main(void){
    int N = 15;
    printf("%i\n", sumN(N));
    printf("%i\n", sumN2(N));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Output

```
120 
120
```

because 15+14+13+12+11+10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 120